# Como hacer un Scroll con multiples layauts?

Tags: android

Tengo problemas al hacer el scroll.

Cree múltiples layouts para hacer un formulario con imágenes y cajas de texto. Pero a la hora de compilar y probar, no hace scroll

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context="com.altafulla.lostdocument.login">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_email"
            android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtemaill"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
</LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:src="@mipmap/pass"
            android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtpass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:hint="Contraseña"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
</LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:src="@mipmap/pass"
            android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtrpass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:hint="Repetir Contraseña"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

         </LinearLayout


         </LinearLayout>
         </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Seria bueno que describieras tu problema, para saber que es lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: Ya detalle lo que sucede.

Answer (score 0):

Coloca el `ScrollView` dentro de un `RelativeLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.altafulla.lostdocument.login">

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

               <ImageView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:background="@android:color/white"
                   android:padding="1dp"
                   android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_email"
                   android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

               <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/txtemaill"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:background="@android:color/white"
                   android:hint="Email"
                   android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                   android:textSize="25sp"/>
           </LinearLayout>


           <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:src="@mipmap/pass"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtpass"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:hint="Contraseña"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />
            </LinearLayout>



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:src="@mipmap/pass"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtrpass"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:hint="Repetir Contraseña"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No, no funciono, sigue sin hacer el Scoll

Comment: Si claro, es porque el codigo tiene un error, ya edito la respuesta.

Comment: Editó el código? veo todo igual, dónde está el error?

Comment: Agregue estas dos líneas que faltaban en el RelativeLayout `android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: @VíctorAltafulla Mira, ya recibe bien tu pregunta y el scroll no te va a funcionar a menos que haya desbordamiento de contenido, osea que se salga de la pantalla. Y por lo que veo tus vistas no llegan a ocupar ni la mitad de la pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

El scrollview de android solo puede contener un hijo, dentro del hijo principal podes meter tus otros layouts. te dejo un ejemplo.

```
<ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout>  <!-- El unico hijo del ScrollView-->

    <!-- Aca pueden ir todos tus layouts necesarios -->
  </LinearLayou>
</ScrollView>
```